# Insert 2 array value to mysql db

Tags: php

I'm getting 2 fields from my html form which store the value in an **Array**.

```
$ingredients = $_POST['ingredients'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
```

I want to insert these 2 value to my mysql db. So I'm using following:

```
foreach($ingredients  as $in)
{
    foreach($quantity as $q)
    {
        echo "Intredent and quantity is : $in and $q<br/>"; 

        //$insert = my mysql Insert query;
    }
}
```

But it showing twice value. For ex: if it's 2 value it's showing 4 value.. etc.

Comment: have you check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach($ingredients as $key => $in)
{
    echo "Intredent and quantity is : $in and $_POST['quantity'][$key]<br/>";
}
```

Are you trying to do that? Each ingredient with the quantity amount?

Comment: @Nikoia I'm trying it now.

Comment: @Babu you're welcome :) Also, welcome to StackOverflow, you can check the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$ingredients = $_POST['ingredients'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

$arr_count = sizeof($ingredients);

for($i=0; $i<$arr_count; $i++)
{
    $in = $ingredients[$i];
    $q = $quantity[$i];

      echo "Intredent and quantity is : $in and $q<br/>"; 

       //$insert = my mysql Insert query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The two loops are not necessary.

```
foreach($ingredients as $index => $in)
{
        echo "Intredent and quantity is : $in and $quantity[$index]<br/>";
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO <table>(<column1>,<column2>) VALUES ($in, $quantity[$index])");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset ($_POST["ingredients"]) && isset($_POST["quantity"]))
{
        $sql = "insert into <table> <column1> = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["ingredients"]).", <column2> = ".ctype_digit($_POST["quantity"]);
        mysql_query($sql);
        //echo your values here
}
```

since I'm such a newb it won't let me comment but if you echo stuff in your foreach it will loop through and change your values